# Firebase facebook authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Facebook Login as authentication in firebase and as I guess `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` needs an internet connection,but asking user turn internet connection while trying to logOut from the app is not good solution I think,so what could be alternative for preventing the user to have multiple credential for firebase?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that `FirebaseUser` auth tokens expires. [This](https://jwt.io/) is a website where the token can be verified.

If you use `getToken(true)`, a new token will be created. This involves the linked providers token validation on the firebase servers, for example validating against Facebook authentication whether the user still has the account linked. Note that the latter counts towards your daily token service quotas. Make sure you use it only when it's necessary.

If a force refresh is not taking place, for example you are using `firebaseUser.getToken(false)`, the returned token will not be updated automatically only if it has expired.

There will be no user with multiple credentials.

Comment: to be honest I couldn't understand everything clearly,so in conlusion,if I will not use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); there still will not be multiple credentials right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There will not be multiple credentials.